# Avoid double recursive call in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, program-transformation

I have this Prolog code:

```erlang
f([ ],-1).

f([H|T],S):- f(T,S1), S1>0, !, S is S1+H.

f([_|T],S):- f(T,S1), S is S1.
```

How can I avoid the second (redundant) recursive call  `f(T,S1)`, in the third clause, the overall effect of predicate remaining the same?

I know that this could be done by defining an additional predicate.

How can such predicate be defined?

Comment: Please indicate several examples of using this predicate. This might help you a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we re-write it a little bit to see the similarities better,

```
f([ ],-1).
f([H|T],S) :- f(T,S1), S1>0, !, S is S1+H.
f([H|T],S) :- f(T,S1),          S is S1.
```

Next we factor out the equal part, and replace its continuation with the new predicate that will do the same thing as was done before, with the same logical variables as were involved there before:

```
f([ ],-1).
f([H|T],S) :- f(T,S1), additional_predicate(S1,S,H).
```

Now all that's left to do is to write the same goals under the new name:

```
additional_predicate(S1,S,H):- S1>0, !, S is S1+H.
additional_predicate(S1,S,H):- S is S1.
```

And that's that.

Put simply, after the call to `f(T,S1)` is done, `S1` is already calculated, so there's no need to recalculate it anew.

Comment: ? When will the first clause of `additional_predicate/3` ever be used?

Comment: the question as I read it is about the transformation of a predicate, not about its meaning.

Comment: But even then, the first clause is useless

Comment: I show a syntactical transformation, so it can be used as a pattern, in other similar cases. eliminating dead code fragments is a semantical transformation.

Comment: Your transformation relies upon your unstated semantic assumption that the cut has no effect on `f(T,S1)`. So you are just as semantic as I am.

Comment: my transformation is purely syntactic. its *correctness* is probably semantic as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

```
?- length(L,_), f(L,R).
   L = [], R = -1
;  L = [_A], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I], R = -1
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J], R = -1
;  ... .
```

Does this ring a bell?

Well, here is what I would respond:

```
f(L, -1) :-
   length(L, _).
```

Although this now terminates and fails for `f(L, 0)` whereas the original definition looped. In case you insist on this equivalence as well:

```
f(L, MinusOne) :-
   length(L, _),
   MinusOne = -1.
```

Comment: yes the definition doesn't make much sense but still this wasn't the question....